# Spark [Scala]: How to solve it: breaking the problem of serialisation using MLWritable for Customised Estimator with customised Params

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The concept of serialisation in Spark/Scala is multifaceted, it includes the Scala component in the language side, or how to use the built-in component in the Spark side. I also have a customised parameters so I cannot easily use the built-in serialisation in Spark. My question is:

*How to solve the customised estimator serialisation in Spark by extending an estimator using MLWritable*.

For built-in estimator we use `save` and `load`. However, if we have a customised estimator, with added params what are the steps for breaking down the problem of serialisation? What are the usual steps to add this functionality? For adding transformers and estimators, the template we can use is pretty standard, do we have a "how to" approach for the serialisation as well?

Coding wise, the solution should go to the `write` method:

```
class CoolAndCustomised extends Estimator[CoolAndCustomisedModel] 
                        with ThisCustomisedParam 
                        with ThatCustomisedParam 
                        with MLWritable {

  //...

  //Question is here, how to derive to the solution and adding it here: 
  override def write: MLWriter = ???

}
```

Comment: Is your problem in implementing `CoolAndCustomised` or making it serializable?

Comment: @gorros serialisation

Comment: Then please add you error. But initially I think you need to register your new class to be serializable.

Comment: I will update the code, however the point here for me at least is, how do you go about solving it? We cant develop based on errors, it become too time consuming. You know if I say, how do we create a dataframe from a case class, we dont need to see the error to come up with a solution there is a general solution that we can use, without looking at the error.

Comment: General solution is to register your class https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#data-serialization

Comment: @gorros If not mistaking it, this serialisation is different concept. I want to use `.save()` on the PipelineStage component.